# Trying to identify this box on the outside of my house

Tags: exterior

This was under a small panel. Don't know what it is, or what it's used for.

[image]

Comment: They look like weather-proof shrouds for low-volt connections like telco or such.  Have you pulled any out to see what the rest looks like?  What's on the other side of the wall?  Also, where is your house (generally speaking)?

Comment: The other side is the garage. Nearby is the condensation drain for the AC. Checking the attic over the garage they appear to run in a bundle and slowly branch out as they head towards the living areas, can't find the other ends. House is in Phoenix.

Comment: What branches out?  Are they wires?  Perhaps this was an alarm system?

Comment: Do you have a photo of the cover, and are there any markings on it?

Comment: Maybe a fiber optic distribution box?

Comment: That's the internet, don't mess with it. You see, the internet is made up of these tubes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is somewhat new construction, these might be anti-pest defense tubes. The exterior box resembles "Tubes in the Wall" pest defense system. Liquid pesticide is shot via CO2 at the exterior junction box and the liquid will travel throughout the house by means of the tubes.

http://www.pestdefense.com/taexx is an example of this sort of system.

[image: Exterior junction box for "Tubes in the Wall"]

**Further Readings**:

[Tubes in the Wall](http://pestcemetery.com/tubes-wall/)

Comment: +1 looks like it to me. Utility lines would have something from the outside connecting in. The ["tubes in the wall"](http://pestcemetery.com/tubes-wall/) system would just be the air-tight tubes.

Comment: downvoting because a more plausible idea is that it has to do with telco, networking, etc. Not insects... unless its proved otherwise and then I'll restore the upvote.

Comment: +1 - Those do look like liquid connections, and there's no evidence of "source" signal coming into the box to be distributed.  This has to be what it is.

Comment: Good thought, but I'm not convinced. The linked system is 1/2"ID pipe around the underground perimeter. This is much smaller radial distribution in the attic to various parts of the house. Still, I have no better answer.

Comment: @bcworkz, have a look at the tubes in the wall link I posted, they're no where near 1/2" ID in some systems. I'm disagreeing with the telco, networking, or other demarcation types, since they'd all require an external connection coming into the box. And who seals their telecomm wiring in airtight tubes?

Comment: @BMitch: It could be silicon to keep bugs out. There is silicon used around any holes my cable company has drilled into my house to keep out bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a box for a NID (network interface device) that a telco would install with 6 weather tight connections installed.  Sometimes the bottom screw hole will be fitted with an anti-tamper device to prevent you from getting into it.

It was probably used to terminate the last mile leg of telephone/cable on the outside of your house, and then often there is an interconnect to connect it into the household wiring (something they can disconnect easily to verify their connection is OK).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a distribution box for cable. as can be seen the six cores have already been used. Are there any wires running inside any of them?

a similar box can be seen [on this link](http://www.postel-overseas.com/pid143278/Wall/Pole-Mounted+Cable+Distribution+Box+%28XF001%29.htm)